# Access order details in success.phtml with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

Currently trying to add some order tracking to our success page, however we need to be able to access information like the value of the order, the number of items ordered, item SKUs etc.

Are there any simple code snippets to access this information or does it all have to be passed manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add below code inside `success.phtml` file,and you can fetch required data using below code,

```
 <?php $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
          echo "<pre>";print_r($orderData->getData());
         //echo $orderData->getData('shipping_description'); //shipping_description
    ?>
```

Comment: This is not the recommended way of doing it in magento 2. Object manager should not be used.

Comment: This gives blank page in 2.1.8

Comment: How to get a country_code from order data?

Comment: @ParasSood What's the recommended method to do it?

Answer (score 5):

To get the order details in the success.phtml , you can use the below code :

```
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $salesOrderFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

/**
* Retrieve current order
*
* @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
*/
public function getOrder()
{
   $orderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
   $order   = $this->_salesFactory->load($orderId);
   return $order->getData(); // you can access various order details from here. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My apologies, but I'm still not too familiar with the frameworks Magento uses. Would the above code be usable on success.phtml or does it need to be done elsewhere?

Comment: You need to override the block vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage/Success.php and define the function `getOrder` in my answer. then you can use the function in success.phtml by `$block->getOrder()`

Answer (score 2):

From Manashvi birla code, I used this :

```
$order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
```

in place of this :

```
$orderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
$order   = $this->_salesFactory->load($orderId);
```

Comment: I tried Manashvi's answer and it gave me an error. But when I fixed it with this, it worked for me.

Comment: Yes it worked for me too!