# Order Details On success page

Tags: magento2, blocks

I am trying to get Order detail on success page by making a custom module and in my block file code is

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
protected $checkoutSession;

/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $oderId;

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $lastOrder;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $lastOrder = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $this->orderId = $lastOrder->getIncrementId();
    $this->lastOrder = $lastOrder->getData();
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getOrderId()
{
    return $this->orderId;
}


public function getSubtotal()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->orderId);
    return $order->getSubtotal();
}

public function getDiscountAmount()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($this->orderId);
    return $order->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

But after place order and on success page getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to CompanyName\Modulename\Block\successpagedata::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory, array given, called in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

I checked code many times but not getting any issue.Can anybody let me know what I am doing wrong.Please help me.

Comment: Did you run `setup:upgrade` and `set:di:compile` commands afterwards??

Comment: Yes,module is working but issue is in code syntax,it seems something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not to inject OrderFactory and use **Service Contracts** instead.

Inject `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` and use `get($id)` method to load any order by id.

**EDIT:**

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
protected $checkoutSession;

/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $oderId;

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $lastOrder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $orderRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $lastOrder = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $this->orderId = $lastOrder->getIncrementId();
    $this->lastOrder = $lastOrder->getData();
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

public function getOrderId()
{
    return $this->orderId;
}


public function getSubtotal()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($this->orderId);
    return $order->getSubtotal();
}

public function getDiscountAmount()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($this->orderId);
    return $order->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: This is being used in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Registration.php`

Comment: Please update code by injecting Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface ,actually I don't have more idea.

Comment: Check my edited asnwer.

Comment: Still same issue  :__construct() must implement interface Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface

Comment: you sure , you ran the compile command after DI

Comment: Actually working in in developer mode hence dont need to compile bur cleaned cache and you can see error changed means code changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65635/discussion-between-sachin-agarwal-and-akgola).

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution for you [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110676/access-order-details-in-success-phtml-with-magento-2) 
**Or** if you want to fix your code. I think you need to pass arguments in your public `__construct` also. **Or** you can use checkout session for get last order on success page. Use [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171096/get-last-order-id-in-magento2) code in block.

Comment: Nothing is working for me.  blank page after trying<?php $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
          echo "<pre>";print_r($orderData->getData());
         //echo $orderData->getData('shipping_description'); //shipping_description
    ?>